A Framework puzzle
About Framework puzzles:

A Framework puzzle is similar to a Fill-in puzzle, except there is no rigid crossword-style grid, the tradeoff here being that you get fewer hints for placing (in this case) numbers in the grid.

The goal of Framework puzzles:

Fill in the grid with the given numbers

To get the green checkmark $\color{\green}✓$:

Solve the Framework



CSV:

Numbers
====================
=Checksum: 14355112=
====================

3-digit  4-digit  5-digit  8-digit
-------  -------  -------  --------
117      1233     11214    14122345
122      2173     11786
176      2315     21567
245      2333     23445
556      3149     51411
         3432     81244
         4999
         5127
         6123

Grid:
+---+---+---+       +---+
|   |   |   |       |   |
+---+---+---+       +---+       +---+
|   |   |   |       |   |       |   |
+---+   +---+---+---+---+       +---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |       |   |
+---+   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |       |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |           |   |       |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+       +---+---+---+---+---+
            |   |   |   |   |   |       |   |   |   |
            +---+---+---+---+---+       +---+   +---+---+---+
            |   |           |   |       |   |   |   |   |   |
            +---+   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
                    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                    |   |       |   |       |   |
                    +---+---+---+---+       +---+
                    |   |   |   |   |       |   |
                    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                                |   |   |   |   |
                                +---+---+---+---+

Solve on Penpa+

Of course, we start with the 8-digit entry...

 
 ...as well as a couple entries which only have one option.

 Next, we can continue up with the 5 sticking out on the upper left. Same deal, several entries have only one number that can fit in them, based solely on what digits have been filled in:


Now, one slightly more advanced deduction than 'only one number fits here' is necessary.

 Note that 8 can't start a 4-digit entry. So the __2__ entry must be 11214, and that allows us to place 81244 on the left.

 After this, the rest falls to 'only one number can fit here' deductions.

The solved grid is:

 


Good job on the quick solve!

step 1: you could have had 112/245

@FlorianF Wouldn't putting 122/245 at the top would lead to a contradiction when trying to solve the bottom half of the grid?

@CrSb0001 Yes, it would, but Deusovi says in step 1 that the only 3-digit entries that will fit there (before filling the rest of the grid) are 245/556.  That is not true, as Florian F pointed out.

@FlorianF Ah, that's a good point, thanks. I'll need to update this answer because my original logical path was broken, and I just got lucky...

I'd say this was a fairly trivial one.
